# Is this a use case for nlp?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I have a list of problems and resolutions. The current search for existing problems is just a keyword search. To improve searching for existing solutions to problems : 
Classify documents based on their semantic meaning using nlp. User enters a search term and documents that closely match this search are displayed alongside possible solutions.

The search will be based on semantic meaning, this is use case for nlp ?

Comment: I am not sure "classifying documents based on their semantic meaning" is a well defined idea. You classify documents based on their content (e.g. word frequencies, n-grams, or fancier features) to find semantic relationships between them.

Answer (score 0):

NLP stand for Natural Language Processing. Thus everything that involves **processing natural language** can be described as NLP. This is not any strict science, this is just a bag term for **everything** related to this field. Even if you just map your text to vector space and forget about any language and semantics, you are still processing natural language, thus - NLP.

Comment: While this is correct and probably the best answer which could be given to this sort of question, it should perhaps be just a comment.